# Are edits just to replace URLs with text links okay?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, edits, hyperlinks

I am new to the edit approval queue and stumbled about multiple edits by the same person which most of the time keep me wondering if this is a valid edit.

The person seems to be mass editing URLs to text links. Some do a good job at that (I approved):

- https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/59255152/3

Sometimes just adding new text that can be used as the link (which I rejected):

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/24823332
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/24825711

And here is one I was not certain about:

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/24825660

Should I accept such edits? Or is this considered blocking the queue?

Comment: Is it an improvement of the content and a non-trivial edit? I would say mostly yes.

Comment: I would argue that it is trivial in most cases, thats why I ask. I approved when it was clearly an improvment but this is not always the case.

Comment: I'm maybe not the *best* person to post an answer here (not yet a yearling), so I'll leave it as a comment. The thing is, reviewers are all (mostly?) human and, as such, we will have a degree of subjectivity in what we consider a good or bad edit. I think maybe that's the point. However, in case of *extremely* trivial edits that really make no improvement, then "Reject" is appropriate. But, sometimes, even a very minor change can give a big improvement (e.g. if OP misspelled "warehouse" as "whorehouse" - it would be a good edit to correct).

Comment: Everything that makes life easier for others is good. Replacing urls with links, image urls with images, code formatting/indention etc. pp. I wish to thank everyone who does these kinds of edits

Comment: Isn't the general rule of thumb for edits that you shouldn't be actively looking for things to edit, that instead you should be editing things you find while using the site normally?

Comment: @user400654 never heard of that. While I can see the intention, the rule would be hard to enforce and in itself is not that convincing.

Comment: @user400654 I always wondered what happens in case actively looking for things is my normal site usage.

Comment: Well, it’s more a case of... instead of doing a cryptic search meant to find a specific type of grammar mistake and fixing it in mass, you fix them as you find them while browsing questions normally. Mass updates tend to be only done in more... visible initiatives, ones started/monitored with a meta post by users with 3k or more rep.

Comment: Having descriptive, readable text instead of bare URLs is also [important for screen readers](https://webaim.org/techniques/hypertext/#screen_readers).

Comment: @user400654: I don't think it is the general rule of thumb, but it ought to be. For instance, editing some of the search engine hits you get when using Stack Overflow as a research tool (or looking for code examples).

Answer (score 7):

My general rule of thumb is that links should be in-lined when you have a large volume of content and the links are contributing to the "wall-of-text" problem. Also, the linkable words are already present. As such, #1 is an acceptable revision.

For #2, there is an attempt to inject a linkable word not originally present, and in #3 the linked word actually makes the link worse by simply injecting a linkable word for the sake of having a linkable word.

Finally, #4 doesn't really improve the post. As such, it's too minor.

Answer (score 6):

I'm generally in favor of removing visible URLs and in-line them behind linked text instead. URLs have the disadvantage of worsen the readability of text when they appear in text walls/paragraphs. Having certain words linked to an URL instead improves the readability and makes the text look less cluttered, also the styling still makes it clear that there is a link placed there.

So such edits shouldn't all be rejected, but it also depends on *how* it has been done.

https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/59255152/3 - that edit of the URLs is fine, but the edit is missing some other issues which need to be fixed.

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/24823332 - that edit is a bit lazy. The added word doesn't improve readability and the kept `:` is also an issue. The whole sentence is currently written to support the URL at the end, so it doesn't actually need to be edited at all.

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/24825711 - another rather lazy replacement. Linking "from" doesn't make sense in that sentence. A better version would be *"Is it acceptable to store a copy of Google's api.js in my extension, or must I load it from Google's repository?"* with a link behind "Google's repository".

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/24825660 - the replacement is ok in my opinion. Instead of "here" we could also use the providers name like *"I followed the guide posted on Rebecca Bilbro's Github page to ...."* with a link behind "Rebecca Bilbro's Github page".

TLDR: such edits are generally fine when they improve the readability and "hide" clutter, but make sure the edited sentence still is *a sentence* and it still makes sense.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, let me be clear, I'm not here to cause any inconvenience to anyone, if I have caused it inadvertently, I would like to apologise right away. I shall improve going forward.

While I was editing all the posts, I had made sure that "I retain the thought process of the owner of the post i.e. without editing the whole sentences". This is the only reason I stayed away from editing whole sentences, as the creator of the post might think that the whole post has been modified.

On the other hand, I have come across many posts that were created, that contain full URLs that are not in line with the text. I took only such posts and making the links in-line.

Unfortunately, Stack Overflow does not get back on why few reviews were "rejected". Otherwise, I would have improved the posts long time ago itself.

Thank you, for bringing this up, **going forward I shall be careful**, since, the guidelines mentioned that the full URLs should be in-line, I am trying to find all the posts and making it in-line.

I would not call the links where I got "rejected" edits as "Lazy edits", as one of the persons have mentioned it, however, as I have pointed it out already, "I did not wanted to make changes to the whole paragraphs" of the posts.

I was only trying to do this for any/all posts that contain links that are not inline.

For example, take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15873126/unable-to-launch-the-iis-express-web-server/15873210#15873210):

BEFORE

> Unable to launch the IIS Express Web server
>   It seems you need to do some configuring as you seem to be using SSL; here's a step-by-step guide by Scott Hanselman himself:
>
> http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WorkingWithSSLAtDevelopmentTimeIsEasierWithIISExpress.aspx

AFTER

> It seems you need to do some configuring as you seem to be using SSL; here's a [step-by-step guide by Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WorkingWithSSLAtDevelopmentTimeIsEasierWithIISExpress.aspx) himself:

Comment: When making any edit, you should make all the corrections, and not just address the problem you want to fix.  Fix capitalization (a lone lowercase "i" is common and should be changed to a capital), spelling, and grammar errors, although making changes to switch from British English to American English (or vice versa) are generally frowned upon .  Improve the formatting for code.  Inline images.  Don't include too much text when creating links.  From your example #1, "guide" or "step-by-step guide" is a sufficiently sized link.

Comment: yes,  i generally take care of misplacement of "links" and "code" only and do not touch "grammer" as you have rightfully pointed out. Will take care going forward.
thank you. Also, where can one find the reasons for the rejected edits.

Comment: As I said thank you for participating and do not feel ashamed for anything you did. You were doing it with good intentions and that is what matters the rest can be picked up while we go, I myself have many questions(as can be seen by this QA). But if you can fix more than just the link please do so. The results of your edit suggestions can be found in your profile. Click "Activity" on the top. Then selection "All actions" in the bar in the middle. There will be another selection bar below where you can select "Suggestions".

Comment: yes, thank you again, i just went to the path you have mentioned, i can see all the accepted and rejected edits, it would be helpful for me going forward.